# How to apply custom styles for Tabs in Angular Material 6?

Tags: css, angular6, angular-material-6

I am using two tab groups namely tab1 and tab2. This is my code:

```
<mat-tab-group class="tab1">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group class="tab2">
  <mat-tab label="Fourth"> Content 4 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Fifth"> Content 5 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Sixth"> Content 6 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Now I need to apply custom CSS differently for both of the tabs (label, label-content, label-height, label-padding). But it is not working. I even tried overriding it with `::ng-deep`, it is not applying. Here's my CSS code:

```
::ng-deep .tab1 > .mat-tab-label-content{
   color: red !important;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

I also tried giving this, but not working:

```
::ng-deep .tab1 .mat-tab-label-content{
   color: red !important;
   min-width: 0;
   padding: 30px;
   margin: 30px;
}
```

So please suggest me how to apply css for each tabs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
.tab1  .mat-tab-label-content {
    color: red;
}
```

See example: https://angular-ekc6jo.stackblitz.io/

Are you sure your CSS is loaded properly?

Comment: This one is not working for me. But other CSS are working.

Comment: You have a public hosted example?